# Debian 4.19.160 dont work with 7-Port Gigabit Ethernet Switch KSZ9897R, but this setup work on 4.9.277

Tags: debian, linux-kernel

i'm using debian 4.19.160 with 7-Port Gigabit Ethernet Switch KSZ9897R.
Network interfaces are visible in the system and are assigned a static address on subnet 111.
But there is no ping to the gateway 192.168.111.253 and other devices in subnet 111.
I hear about phy.c and lan78xx.c pathces, but i cant find it.

Has anyone heard of this problem and can help?

**4.19.160**

**sudo lsusb -t -s [[bus]:1] -v**

```
    /:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=lan78xx, 5000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=lan78xx, 5000M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/7p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/3p, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_acm, 12M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_acm, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_acm, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 6, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_acm, 12M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 23, If 3, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=option, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 23, If 1, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=option, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 23, If 4, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=qmi_wwan, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 23, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=option, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 23, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=option, 480M
```

**sudo lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 025: ID 2c7c:0125 Quectel Wireless Solutions Co., Ltd. EC25 LTE modem
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0483:5740 STMicroelectronics Virtual COM Port
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1546:01a8 U-Blox AG [u-blox 8]
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:8505 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0930:6545 Toshiba Corp. Kingston DataTraveler 102/2.0 / HEMA Flash Drive 2 GB / PNY Attache 4GB Stick
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0451:2036 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB2036 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 0451:9261 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0424:7801 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0424:7801 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**sudo dmesg | grep lan**

```
[    4.743494] libphy: lan78xx-mdiobus: probed
[    4.884731] libphy: lan78xx-mdiobus: probed
[    4.892570] usbcore: registered new interface driver lan78xx
[    5.239025] lan78xx 4-1:1.0 enp1s0u1: renamed from eth0
[    5.259252] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    5.259255] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    5.282555] lan78xx 4-2:1.0 enp1s0u2: renamed from eth1
```

**sudo dmesg | grep enp**

```
[    3.343518] igb 0000:0a:00.0 enp10s0: renamed from eth0
[    5.239025] lan78xx 4-1:1.0 enp1s0u1: renamed from eth0
[    5.282555] lan78xx 4-2:1.0 enp1s0u2: renamed from eth1
[    5.604703] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0u1: link is not ready
[    5.615135] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0u2: link is not ready
[    5.668963] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp10s0: link is not ready
[    6.623792] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp1s0u2: link becomes ready
[    6.623872] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp1s0u1: link becomes ready
[    9.184244] igb 0000:0a:00.0 enp10s0: igb: enp10s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[    9.184514] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp10s0: link becomes ready
```

**sudo lsmod | grep lan**

```
lan78xx                61440  0
fixed_phy              16384  3 lan78xx
libphy                 77824  4 fixed_phy,lan78xx
usbcore               294912  13 usbserial,xhci_hcd,usbnet,usbhid,cdc_acm,usb_storage,cdc_wdm,usb_wwan,qmi_wwan,xhci_pci,lan78xx,uas,option
```

**sudo ifconfig -a**

```
enp10s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.88.242  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.88.255
        inet6 fe80::213:95ff:fe33:c979  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:13:95:33:c9:79  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 9467  bytes 1197188 (1.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 589  bytes 91476 (89.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0x91900000-9191ffff  

enp1s0u1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.111.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.111.255
        inet6 fe80::89c:8ff:fe90:8520  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0a:9c:08:90:85:20  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 453  bytes 68160 (66.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp1s0u2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.111.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.111.255
        inet6 fe80::cc2e:d5ff:fec8:d76d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ce:2e:d5:c8:d7:6d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 67  bytes 11758 (11.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 111523  bytes 23797265 (22.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 111523  bytes 23797265 (22.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wwp0s21f0u8i4: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether e6:6c:e3:84:85:a0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**ping 192.168.111.253**

```
From 192.168.111.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.111.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.111.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.111.1 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.111.1 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.111.1 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.111.1 icmp_seq=7 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.111.1 icmp_seq=8 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.111.1 icmp_seq=9 Destination Host Unreachable
```

**ip route**

```
default via 192.168.111.253 dev enp1s0u1 onlink 
192.168.88.0/24 dev enp10s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.88.242 
192.168.111.0/24 dev enp1s0u1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.111.1 
192.168.111.0/24 dev enp1s0u2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.111.2
```

**sudo netstat -r**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         192.168.111.253 0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp1s0u1
192.168.88.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp10s0
192.168.111.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp1s0u1
192.168.111.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp1s0u2
```

**4.9.277**
**sudo lsusb -t -s [[bus]:1] -v**

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=lan78xx, 5000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=lan78xx, 5000M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/7p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/3p, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_acm, 12M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_acm, 12M
```

**sudo lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1546:01a8 U-Blox AG [u-blox 8]
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:8505 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0930:6545 Toshiba Corp. Kingston DataTraveler 102/2.0 / HEMA Flash Drive 2 GB / PNY Attache 4GB Stick
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0451:2036 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB2036 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 0451:9261 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0424:7801 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0424:7801 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**sudo dmesg | grep lan**

```
[    6.345656] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    6.345657] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    6.390829] libphy: lan78xx-mdiobus: probed
[    6.525199] libphy: lan78xx-mdiobus: probed
[    6.525542] usbcore: registered new interface driver lan78xx
[    6.615561] lan78xx 4-1:1.0 enp1s0u1: renamed from eth0
[    6.634560] lan78xx 4-2:1.0 enp1s0u2: renamed from eth1
[    7.247051] lan78xx 4-1:1.0 enp1s0u1: registered fixed PHY
[    7.250712] lan78xx 4-1:1.0 enp1s0u1: kevent 4 may have been dropped
[    7.297206] lan78xx 4-2:1.0 enp1s0u2: registered fixed PHY
[    7.304438] lan78xx 4-2:1.0 enp1s0u2: kevent 4 may have been dropped
```

**sudo dmesg | grep enp**
[    2.490586] igb 0000:0a:00.0 enp10s0: renamed from eth0
[    6.615561] lan78xx 4-1:1.0 enp1s0u1: renamed from eth0
[    6.634560] lan78xx 4-2:1.0 enp1s0u2: renamed from eth1
[    7.247051] lan78xx 4-1:1.0 enp1s0u1: registered fixed PHY
[    7.250712] lan78xx 4-1:1.0 enp1s0u1: kevent 4 may have been dropped
[    7.250830] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0u1: link is not ready
[    7.297206] lan78xx 4-2:1.0 enp1s0u2: registered fixed PHY
[    7.304438] lan78xx 4-2:1.0 enp1s0u2: kevent 4 may have been dropped
[    7.304502] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0u2: link is not ready
[    7.381030] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp10s0: link is not ready
[    8.257640] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp1s0u1: link becomes ready
[    8.316187] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp1s0u2: link becomes ready
[ 2397.224737] igb 0000:0a:00.0 enp10s0: igb: enp10s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
[ 2397.332464] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp10s0: link becomes ready

**sudo lsmod | grep lan**

```
lan78xx                45021  0
```

**sudo ifconfig -a**

```
enp10s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.88.128  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.88.255
        inet6 fe80::213:95ff:fe33:c979  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:13:95:33:c9:79  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 69706  bytes 18005335 (17.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 52954  bytes 9733151 (9.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0x91900000-9191ffff  

enp1s0u1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.111.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.111.255
        inet6 fe80::f8ca:13ff:fe29:20d0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fa:ca:13:29:20:d0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 11861  bytes 1368300 (1.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 476  bytes 326640 (318.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp1s0u2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.111.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.111.255
        inet6 fe80::5c10:adff:fe4a:e4c3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 5e:10:ad:4a:e4:c3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 381  bytes 322566 (315.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2844572  bytes 356924080 (340.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2844572  bytes 356924080 (340.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**ping 192.168.111.253**

```
PING 192.168.111.253 (192.168.111.253) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.111.253: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.313 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.111.253: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.296 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.111.253: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.322 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.111.253: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.389 ms
```

**ip route**

```
default via 192.168.88.1 dev enp10s0 
192.168.88.0/24 dev enp10s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.88.128 
192.168.111.0/24 dev enp1s0u1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.111.1 
192.168.111.0/24 dev enp1s0u2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.111.2
```

**sudo netstat -r**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         vpn.prk-a.ru    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp10s0
192.168.88.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp10s0
192.168.111.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp1s0u1
192.168.111.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp1s0u2
```

Comment: Please copy&paste all command output **as text** and format it as code blocks. Show the output of a non-working `ping` and the output of `netstat -r`. What switch do you have? "KSZ9897R" is a chip type. Do you have a switch as a separate device based on this chip? Is this chip integrated in some other device, e.g. in your router?

Comment: @Bodo added `netstat -r` and `ip route`. Sorry, I don't know all the connection details. If i dont mistake, it connected by usb to my motherboard. Also i know, that i have SuperSpeed USB 3.1 Gen 1 to 10/100/1000Ethernet Controller with RGMII, after switch

Comment: To me it is still unclear what hardware you are using. Why do you have two interfaces `enp1s0u1` and `enp1s0u2`?  Does the USB network interface appear as two devices? Or did you connect two separate devices? Please add all requested information or clarification to the question, don't use comments for this purpose.

Comment: @Bodo ok, thanks. 
I'll find out and write in the description

Comment: I think this switch uses these two interfaces as management interface and cpu (data) interface and a DSA/switchdev architecture. The 5 physical ports aren't directly visible in such case. Maybe they could appear as vlan interfaces or alike once properly configured. I'm not even sure there's support for KSZ9897**R** in the latest kernel (only KSZ9897). This requires a kernel with options not built on a default Debian kernel, at least: CONFIG_NET_DSA : https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NET_DSA.html . But maybe everything written doesn't apply to the "R" model, who knows...

Comment: @A.V Yeah, you right about two interfaces as management interface. I will read and try

Comment: @A.V Also it strange, that my setup work on linux-4.9, but doesnt work on 4.19

Comment: You should then update your question and show the working setup

Comment: btw it's @A.B heh

Comment: @A.B i'm updated question and added output of the same command, but on 4.9.

Comment: I don't know what to add. Except 1/ it's never a good idea to put two interfaces in the same (IPv4) LAN as was done here 2/ I thought the question was about using/addressing the 5 physical ports of the switch, not how to get basic connectivity: these ports don't appear any better with kernel 4.9